# If I restructure data for use, how can I make Firebase automatically update it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-structures, firebase, angularfire

If I use:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/");                
var sync = $firebase(ref);                                
var firebaseData= sync.$asObject();
```

`firebaseData` will change as data from `https://myURL.firebaseio.com/` changes. They will be in sync.

If I restructure data, and define it as some new variable `var newStructure`, how can I get it to sync with `https://myURL.firebaseio.com/` or `firebaseData`?

Is there a way I can watch for changes in `firebaseData` and recall the restructuring method?

Is there a way to know what specifically changed in `firebaseData` and make only relevant changes to `newStructure`?

Is there a way that `newStructure` can sync directly with Firebase, albeit have data parsed with a different structure?

Comment: Since you're monitoring the top-level of your Firebase, your `firebaseData` object will receive all updates to that Firebase. But I don't understand what you mean with "restructure data". Can you show some code of what you're trying to do (by clicking the edit link under your question and adding the code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `firebaseData` represents your firebase collection.

All changes you make to `firebaseData` will be syncronized across connections:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/");                
var sync = $firebase(ref);                                
var firebaseData = sync.$asObject();
```

You can watch to see if any changes have been made to the object:

```
firebaseData.$watch(function(event){
    console.log("Change made to this firebase object");
    // Then you can call a function which could restructure your data:
    restructureData(firebaseData, event);
});
```

So your `restructureData` function could look like this:

```
var restructureData = function(firebaseObj, event){
    // This function updates firebase on every change to firebase
    // But we don't want to update it again after running this function
    if(event.key === "changesMadeToFirebase") return;
    firebaseObj.changesMadeToFirebase += 1;
    firebaseObj.$save().then(function(){
        console.log("data restructured");
    }, function(err){
        console.log("There was an error:", err);
    });
};
```

This allows you to check how many changes have been made to firebase, except for the changes to the field `"changesMadeToFirebase"`

Although this is a very small example, you will be able to find much more here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html