# How to drill down JSON with ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs

I have been stuck on displaying data with ng-repeat. the only thing I have been able to do is display the one of the  two objects. Every Customer can have multiple Users. I am trying to display the Users in a table with there CustomerId.
[Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CwMa7PEbTj1nHGSDcqeM?p=preview)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
var json = [
    {
        "CustomerId": "12xsd-344-fv23", "CompanyName": "ConocoPhillips",
        "Address": "1234 Main St", "City": "Redmond", "State": "WA", "Zip": "10999",
        "Email": "debra@example.com",
        "Users": [
             {
                 "FirstName": "Rudy", "LastName": "Sanchez", "CustomerId": "12xsd-344-fv23", "Customer": null,
                 "Email": "admin@energy.com", "EmailConfirmed": true, "PasswordHash": "AGtuCXr",
                 "SecurityStamp": "b0fca140", "PhoneNumber": null, "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false, "TwoFactorEnabled": false,
                 "LockoutEndDateUtc": null, "LockoutEnabled": false, "AccessFailedCount": 0, "Roles": [], "Claims": [], "Logins": [],
                 "Id": "49b5", "UserName": "admin"
             },
             {
                 "FirstName": "Troy", "LastName": "Benbow", "CustomerId": "12xsd-344-fv23", "Customer": null,
                 "Email": "tbenbow@yahoo.com", "EmailConfirmed": true, "PasswordHash": "AM8wL+iHaSG",
                 "SecurityStamp": "14f1483a-2e6f-41da-8307-a6c5945984a9", "PhoneNumber": null, "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false, "TwoFactorEnabled": false,
                 "LockoutEndDateUtc": null, "LockoutEnabled": true, "AccessFailedCount": 0, "Roles": [], "Claims": [], "Logins": [],
                 "Id": "9985b820-a45", "UserName": "tbenbow"
             }
        ]
    },
];
$scope.customers = json;
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, `CustomerId` is *also* a property of `User`, you could make a list of `Users` in the controller and then loop them in the table:

```
  $scope.users = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.customers[i].Users.length; j++) {

        //now you have access to customer properties with $scope.customers[i]
        var user = $scope.customers[i].Users[j];

        //example of adding CompanyName property
        user.CompanyName = $scope.customers[i].CompanyName;  

        //add user to $scope.users 
        $scope.users.push(user);
    }

  }
```

And then just `ng-repeat` the `users`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>{{user.FirstName}} {{user.LastName}}</td>
  <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
  <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
  <td>{{user.CustomerId}}</td>
  <td>{{user.CustomerName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XFujRzkcIuaUUXVx7Fs?p=preview).

In fact, even if you need a property on the parent `Customer` part of `json`, you can add the property to the `users` array being repeated.

Preparing the data for view will often simplify template *tricks* (like having to build the table with extra `ng-repeat`ed elements.  IMO, this is preferable.

Comment: I forgot to mention I need to be able to add some Customer properties to the same table. That's why I was trying to go through the customers to the users data. Sorry.

Comment: Like I mentioned, you can easily do this in the same loop (as you prepare the `users` array).  You can add a further loop for each user and then add the properties from the parent.

Comment: Sorry. I should take more time to read everything. So where exactly would I add the parents property? I'm kind of lost on adding a additional loop. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've made an update showing how to add the parent properties during the loop.  I've also updated the plunker to include CompanyName (from customer).

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions for this problem, the first one ( rearranging your data in your controller) has already been mentioned in the other answer.

Another way would be a nested loop which I implemented like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>UserName</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>CustomerId</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="customer in customers">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in customer.Users">
        <td>{{user.FirstName}} {{user.LastName}} {{customer.CustomerId}}</td>
        <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
        <td>{{user.CustomerId}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution is fast and easy to implement and gives you access to both the user and customer. I would still suggest to rebuild your data in your controller most of the time as it keeps your views clean and keeps any real logic in your controller ([Check here for an example of that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418968/4360457)).

But this example is so simple that you can easily handle it in a nested ng-repeat.

Comment: This will repeat a `tbody` for every customer, which is not valid HTML.  But, it might work in some browsers.

Comment: @DavinTryon I am not sure about the validity of the html but as far as I know it should work in any browser ( see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076790/4360457) ; the fifth comment in particular) , please let me know if there is a case where this doesn't work.

Comment: I went with data in the controller as you suggested. this did work fine though. thank you very muc!